# How to split server connection with VLANs?

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

first of all, i wasn't able to find a good heading. If someone has a better one feel free to edit.

Today I got a new server and now I am trying to configure it, but I have a little problem.
I want to split the servers connections, some stuff like Apache and MySQL should be only available through it internet port (eth1), some stuff like NAS or SSH only be available through its intranet port (eth0) and some should be available on both, like game or mail servers.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.10.1
  netmask 255.255.240.0
  network 192.168.0.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.10
  netmask 255.255.240.0
  network 192.168.0.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.4.4
```

This is my interfaces configuration and my VLAN are configured like this (port based VLAN) 01 is Router, 03 is eth0, 04 is eth1, 05-08 are PC's):

```
VLAN    01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
  01     X        X
  02     X           X  X  X  X
  03           X     X  X  X  X
```

In this configuration all PC's can reach the Server with eth1's address (.1.10) but not with eth0's (.10.1)

From the WAN address, which has all ports forwarded to eth1's address, you can reach the server like intended.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

```
VLAN    01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
  01     X        X
  02     X           X  X  X  X
  03              X  X  X  X  X
```

This configuration works fine, but it isn't really what I intended, because eth0 on 03 is a 1Gbps link and eth1 on 04 only 100Mbps

Comment: You write that you are using "port based VLAN". But then there should not be more than one VLAN assigned to any port.

Comment: So if that is the problem, what is the proper solution to have the connections managed like in the first VLAN scheme?

Comment: Well, your question is rather unclear so it is hard to make a diagnosis. You wrote that the PCs can reach the server on 1.10 but not on 10.1. You realize that - with the configuration given abovew - you can reach the 10.1 address only from another 10.x address? So your PCs would need to have two IPs as well. Also it is really not clear what you want to achieve, e.g. why you think you need two IP addresses on your server to separate/block traffic. And when doing VLAn you should do proper 802.1q VLANs with tagging where needed.